# How do I get a response/information from a hanging pgPool.connect()?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, node-postgres, pgpool

I am using the pg package (node.js), and for some reason the connect function gives me nothing. My code gets hung up on that line and I'm unable to see any errors, what's wrong, or what's happening.

i.e.

```
console.log("HERE");
await pgPool.connect()
console.log("NOW HERE") //this line never prints
```

I've tried a bunch of variations too:

```
console.log("HERE");
const client = await pgPool.connect()
console.log(client) //this line never prints
```

Does anyone know how to get a verbose stream from pg? My pg version is 7.15.0 and my npm version is 6.14.4

I've tried waiting it out for over an hour. For friends running the same code from the same branch on their local machines it connects in under a second. I've confirmed they have the same version of pg as me.

I am able to connect directly to the database using `psql` in a separate terminal without issues (it immediately connects in < 1 second)

Comment: Does the process end?  If not, how long have you waited?

Comment: @jjanes no it does not, I've waited a while, for coworkers pulling the same code on their machine it connects in under 1 second

Comment: It sounds like there is a firewall or something which is blackholing your connection.  That is, dropping the connection attempt, but not telling it has done so.  Can you try to connect from another tool (on your local machine), like `psql`?  "a while" is not very precise, can you just let it run overnight

Comment: @jjanes I am able to connect with psql without issue. (so I know it's not a firewall or credentials issue) Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Updated my pg to 8.2.1 and it solved the problem. Must be an incompatibility issue with an earlier version

Answer (score 1):

Updated my pg to 8.2.1 and it solved the problem. Must be an incompatibility issue with an earlier version